# What is time complexity of BFS traversal in different types of graph implementations?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search

Here is the bfs traversal code that I have created. I am working with undirected and unweighted graphs only.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getBFSResult() {
    int noOfVertices = getNoOfVertices(), exploredNodesCount = 0;
    boolean visitedVertices[] = new boolean[noOfVertices];
    ArrayList<Integer> bfsResult = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    
    if(noOfVertices > 0) {
        queue.add(0);
        visitedVertices[0] = true;
        while(!queue.isEmpty() && exploredNodesCount < noOfVertices) {
            int idx = queue.peek();
            ArrayList<Integer> adjacentNodes = getAdjacentNodes(idx);
            for(int i: adjacentNodes) {
                if(!visitedVertices[i]) {
                    queue.add(i);
                    visitedVertices[i] = true;
                }
            }
            int exploredNodeIndex = queue.remove();
            bfsResult.add(exploredNodeIndex);
            exploredNodesCount++;
        }   
    }
    return bfsResult;
}
```

According to the above code I deduced the following results:

For Graph using edge list getBFSResult() has a time complexity

of O(|V|*(|E|+ 1) + 2*|E|) which is O(|V|*|E| + |V| + 2*|E|)

where |V| represents the number of vertices and |E| represents

the number of edges in the graph.

|E| is the time complexity for getAdjacentNodes(idx); and it is

run |V| times.

2*|E| is the total number of times the for loop runs until the

while loop finishes.

1 is time taken by the statements having constant time.

---

For Graph using adjacency matrix getBFSResult() has a time

complexity of O(|V|*(|V|+ 1) + 2*|E|) which is

O(|V|^2 + |V| + 2*|E|) where |V| represents the number of

vertices and |E| represents the number of edges in the graph.

|V| is the time complexity for getAdjacentNodes(idx); and it is

run |V| times.

2*|E| is the total number of times the for loop runs until the

while loop finishes.

1 is time taken by the statements having constant time

complexity in one iteration of the while loop.

---

For Graph using adjacency list getBFSResult() has a time

complexity of O(|V|*|V| + 2*|E| + |V|)) which is

O(|V|^2 + 2*|E| + |V|) where |V| represents the number of

vertices and |E| represents the number of edges in the graph.

|V| is the time complexity for getAdjacentNodes(idx); and it is

run |V| times.

2*|E| is the total number of times the for loop runs until the

while loop finishes.

1 is time taken by the statements having constant time

complexity in one iteration of the while loop.

Note: We have not considered the time complexity of the
bfsResult.add(visitedNodeIndex); because it is there just to
collect the bfs result and its time complexity until the
while loop ends is O(|V|*(|V|+1)/2).

The problem I face is that in the internet the time complexity for:

Graph using edge list is O(|E|^2)

Graph using adjacency list is O(|V| + |E|)

and I am not able to derive these results based on my above code for BFS?
What am I missing?

Comment: *"based on my above code for DFS"* ... Did you mean BFS?

Comment: Yes, it is BFS.